# how to resize flexbox children to equal width with an uneven amount of items per row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a grid in HTML that layouts all it's children to have the same width. I'd also like to have that Flexbox wrap-behavior meaning it should create new rows once the window gets resized. I'dont want the items to have a fixed size for every dimension. The height of the rows should be determined by its largest child [Image 2]. So far I've managed to get the children equally sized only if every row contains the same amount of items. I've already tried to manipulate the flex-shrink and flex-grow properties and I've also added invisible placeholders. Neither managed to achieve my desired result. I'm rather new to CSS, any help would be highly appreciated. Cheers!

```css
.collection-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0px auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.collection-item {
  margin: 10px;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<span class="collection-container">
        <div class="collection-item">
            <h5>Headline 1</h5>
            <ul>
                <li >feature</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collection-item">
            <h5>very long Headline</h5>
            <ul>
                <li >feature</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collection-item">
            <h5>Short HL</h5>
            <ul>
                <li >feature</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collection-item">
            <h5>Longer Headline</h5>
            <ul>
                <li >feature</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collection-item">
            <h5>Headline</h5>
            <ul>
                <li >feature</li>
                <li >feature</li>
                <li >feature</li>
                <li >feature</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collection-item">
            <h5>Headline</h5>
            <ul>
                <li >feature</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collection-item">
            <h5>Longer Headline</h5>
            <ul>
                <li >feature</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collection-item">
            <h5>Headline</h5>
            <ul>
                <li >feature</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </span>
```

[What I've got so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t1Gx.png)
[What I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKtlP.png)

Answer (score 0):

This looks working.

1. I added **justify-content: flex-start** to  **.collection-container** ...
2. ... and commented out  in **flex-basis** and **flex-grow** in **.collection-container**

```css
.collection-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0px auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.collection-item {
  margin: 10px;
  //flex-basis: 0;
  //flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<span class="collection-container">
        <div class="collection-item">
            <h5>Headline</h5>
            <ul>
                <li >feature</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collection-item">
            <h5>Headline</h5>
            <ul>
                <li >feature</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collection-item">
            <h5>Headline</h5>
            <ul>
                <li >feature</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collection-item">
            <h5>Headline</h5>
            <ul>
                <li >feature</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collection-item">
            <h5>Headline</h5>
            <ul>
                <li >feature</li>
                <li >feature</li>
                <li >feature</li>
                <li >feature</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collection-item">
            <h5>Headline</h5>
            <ul>
                <li >feature</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collection-item">
            <h5>Headline</h5>
            <ul>
                <li >feature</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collection-item">
            <h5>Headline</h5>
            <ul>
                <li >feature</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </span>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the cells are still not equal in width if one of the headlines is longer forcing the item to expand.

Comment: I think you can solve the unequal width problem by using `width: clamp(min, ideal, max)` with the `.collection-container` class. You'll get equal widths but the container won't grow in a fluid manner.